# Allowing only rectangular selection with checkbox grid

Tags: javascript, html, math

Sorry for the confusing title, I really could not think of anything better.

Say my client has a square space on their homepage where they can upload images which can be placed on any number of boxes in a grid.

The selection of boxes an image should occupy looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[1]" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[2]" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[3]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[4]">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[5]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[6]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[7]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[8]">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/17zt26wb/4/

However, as images can only be rectangular, I want to prevent them from choosing something like this:

X - X - O - O

X - O - O - O

`var selection = {p1: true, p2: true, p3: false, p4: false, p5: true, p6: false, p7: false, p8: false};`

OR:

O - O - X - X

X - O - O - O

`var selection = {p1: false, p2: false, p3: true, p4: true, p5: true, p6: false, p7: false, p8: false};`

However, this is valid:

X - O - O - O

O - O - O - O

`var selection = {p1: true, p2: false, p3: false, p4: false, p5: false, p6: false, p7: false, p8: false};`

OR:

O - X - X - X

O - X - X - X

`var selection = {p1: false, p2: true, p3: true, p4: true, p5: false, p6: true, p7: true, p8: true};`

etc.

I need help figuring out and algorithm that will return either true/false if the selected checkboxes represent a square/rectangle. This could be done in Javascript but it does not really matter - I just need something to start with, I will port it to my language myself.

In the fiddle, the first two checkboxes are disabled, because an image already occupies those two blocks. Values of p1 and p2 in the *selection* object are always false.

Is this even possible? I may just not care about the validation, but it would be nice to have.

Edit: To clarify, the grid size should always stay as 4x2, however, it would be nice to have the option to change the size with constants.

Comment: I count.... 28... valid combinations. It's a small enough domain that you could just hardcode the valid combinations. If your grid were 30x30 (for example) this would not be a valid option and you'd need an algorithm, But for this small a domain id just give up and hardcode the valid ones.

Comment: I thought about that. Technically, the grid size will always be 4x2, but it's not impossible to change in the future. Worst case scenario, if nobody has a better idea, I'll probably just hardcode it.

Comment: There are smart ways to "hardcode" it so you can easily add rules in the future - working on an answer for you

Comment: Thank you. I changed the example fiddle a bit, the first two checkboxes don't need to be checked, just disabled. Then, p1 and p2 are always false in the selection object, if it makes a difference. I just do not want to complicate things any more than needed.

Comment: NP, you just reduced the surface area quite a lot by disabling/unchecking the 1 & 2 boxes. There are now considerably less than 28 combinations which are valid. I think now only 14 valid combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array of arrays containing the valid "indexes" - as an example(incomplete)

```
// box 5 and 6 alone are valid. 
// 5 & 6 in combination is valid. 
// 3,4,7,8 in combination is valid
// TODO: Add all other valid combinations
var validCombinations = [[5],[6],[5,6],[3,4,7,8]];
```

You can use an algorithm like the below. Note that this is "hardcoding" the valid combinations rather than using a true algorithm to determine if a selection is rectangular.

```js
var validCombinations = [[5],[6],[5,6],[3,4,7,8]];

function isAll(input){
    var $checkedBoxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
    return $checkedBoxes.length == input.length 
             && input.every(function(i){          
                    return $("[name='position[" + i + "]']:checkbox:checked").length;
                })
}

$(':checkbox').click(function(){
   var isValid = validCombinations.some(function(x) { return isAll(x);})
   console.log("Selection is valid?",isValid)
})
```

```css
.row {
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.row .grid-position {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #aaa;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[1]" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[2]" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[3]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[4]">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[5]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[6]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[7]">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position">
        <input type="checkbox" name="position[8]">
    </div>
</div>
```